# SQL Server: What locale should be used to format numeric values into SQL Server format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, globalization

It seems that SQL Server [does not accept numbers formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501487/sql-server-must-numbers-all-be-specified-with-) using any particular locale.
It also doesn't support locales that have digits other than **0-9**.

For example, if the current locale is bengali, then the number **123456789** would come out as **"১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯"**. And that's just the digits, nevermind what the digit grouping would be.

But the same problem happens for numbers in the **Invariant** locale, which formats numbers as "123,456,789", which SQL Server won't accept.

Is there a culture that matches what SQL Server accepts for numeric values? Or will i have to create some custom "sql server" culture, generating rules for that culture myself from lower level formatting routines?

If i was in **.NET** (which i'm not), i could peruse the [Standard Numeric Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). Of the format codes available in .NET:

- c (Currency): $123.46
- d (Decimal): 1234
- e (Exponentional): 1.052033E+003
- f (Fixed Point): 1234.57
- g (General): 123.456
- n (Number): 1,234.57
- p (Percent): 100.00 %
- r (Round Trip): 123456789.12345678
- x (Hexadecimal): FF

Only 6 accept **all** numeric types:

- c (Currency): $123.46
- <strike>d (Decimal): 1234</strike>
- e (Exponentional): 1.052033E+003
- f (Fixed Point): 1234.57
- g (General): 123.456
- n (Number): 1,234.57
- p (Percent): 100.00 %
- <strike>r (Round Trip): 123456789.12345678</strike>
- <strike>x (Hexadecimal): FF</strike>

And of those only 2 generate string representations, in the **en-US** locale anyway, that would be accepted by SQL Server:

- <strike>c (Currency): $123.46</strike>
- <strike>d (Decimal): 1234</strike>
- <strike>e (Exponentional): 1.052033E+003</strike>
- f (Fixed Point): 1234.57
- g (General): 123.456
- <strike>n (Number): 1,234.57</strike>
- <strike>p (Percent): 100.00 %</strike>
- <strike>r (Round Trip): 123456789.12345678</strike>
- <strike>x (Hexadecimal): FF</strike>

Of the remaining two, fixed is dependant on the locale's digits, rather than the number being used, leaving **General g format**:

- <strike>c (Currency): $123.46</strike>
- <strike>d (Decimal): 1234</strike>
- <strike>e (Exponentional): 1.052033E+003</strike>
- <strike>f (Fixed Point): 1234.57</strike>
- g (General): 123.456
- <strike>n (Number): 1,234.57</strike>
- <strike>p (Percent): 100.00 %</strike>
- <strike>r (Round Trip): 123456789.12345678</strike>
- <strike>x (Hexadecimal): FF</strike>

And i can't even say for certain that the **g** format won't add digit groupings (e.g. 1,234).

Is there a locale that formats numbers in the way SQL Server expects? Is there a .NET format code? A java format code? A Delphi format code? A VB format code? A stdio format code?

latin-numeral-digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server specifications for [constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) are describing the acceptable formats in T-SQL expressions and batches:

> **integer** constants are represented by a string of numbers that are not
>   enclosed in quotation marks and do not
>   contain decimal points. Integer
>   constants must be whole numbers; they
>   cannot contain decimals.
>
> **decimal** constants are represented by a string of numbers that are not
>   enclosed in quotation marks and
>   contain a decimal point.
>
> **float** and **real** constants are represented by using scientific
>   notation.
>
> **money** constants are represented as string of numbers with an optional
>   decimal point and an optional currency
>   symbol as a prefix. Money constants are
>   not enclosed in quotation marks. SQL
>   Server does not enforce any kind of
>   grouping rules such as inserting a
>   comma (,) every three digits in
>   strings that represent money. Commas
>   are ignored anywhere in the specified
>   money literal.
>
> To indicate whether a number is **positive** or **negative**, apply the +  or - unary operators to a numeric constant. This creates a numeric expression that represents the signed numeric value. Numeric constants use positive when the + or -  unary operators are not applied.

The good news is that client applications don't need to worry about these requirements. Client applications should pass numeric values as **@parameters**, not as T-SQL literal constants.

Comment: Accepted. +1 for quoting (and bolding no less!) the relevant portions. i never saw this topic in my 2000 BoL.